# Considering an enterprise level application, built on top of scala,python and angularjs, what method would be ideal to get the updates from back-end.

Tags: python, angularjs, scala

I knew that client polling is bad and not recommended for enterprise level applications.
Do we have any 3rd party which notifies client whenever there is a change in data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your backend is a Scala based Web application, you could then expose a Websocket endpoint to which your client subscribes. You then could push data as soon as there is some change in the backend. Whoever is subscribed to this Websocket channel, will get this update.